# Schur multiplier as a subgroup in finite abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group such that the Schur multiplier $M(G)=\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

> Can we say that $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p.$

I have seen in many groups this relation holds, what can we say in general? I don't know that how to prove this or contradict. Please help me.

Comment: No one is looking on this question. Please have a look on this.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your reply sir.How can we see the proof, I am confused with some results like, If $G=\mathbb{Z}_2^4$ then $M(G)$ is of order $64$. So how can we say that $M(G)$ is isomorphic to some subgroup of $M(P)?$

Comment: $G=P$ in your example so the assertion is trivially true.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think Syl_p(G) denotes sylow p subgroup, so how the result is true? Order of subgroup can not exceed the order of group?

Comment: Let me start again. Let $G$ be a finite group, let $M(G)$ be its Schur Multiplier, let $p$ be a prime, and let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then it is a standard result that the $p$-primary part $M(G)_p$ of $M(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $M(P)$. In your question you are assuming that $M(G)$ is itself a $p$-group, so in that situation we have $M(G)_p=M(G)$, and $M(G)$ is isomorphivc to a subgroup of $M(P)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am not understanding that how the result stated by you works upon $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 ?$

Comment: As I said before, the result is completely trivial in that case because $P=G$ so $M(G)=M(P)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok Thanks for your kind support